# can we batch up groups of 10 message load in mosquitto using spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, mqtt, spring-integration-mqtt

this is how i have defined my mqtt connection using spring integration.i am not sure whether this is possible bt can we setup a mqtt subscriber works after getting a 10 load of messages. right now subscriber works after publishing a message as it should.

```
    @Autowired
    ConnectorConfig config;


    @Bean
    public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
        factory.setServerURIs(config.getUrl());
        factory.setUserName(config.getUser());
        factory.setPassword(config.getPass());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageProducer inbound() {
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
                new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(config.getClientid(), mqttClientFactory(), "ALERT", "READING");

        adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
        adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
        adapter.setQos(1);
        adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttRouterChannel());
        return adapter;
    }

   /**this is router**/
   @MessageEndpoint
   public class MessageRouter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageRouter.class);


    static final String  ALERT = "ALERT";
    static final String  READING = "READING";

    @Router(inputChannel = "mqttRouterChannel")
    public String route(@Header("mqtt_topic") String topic){
        String route = null;
        switch (topic){
            case ALERT:
                logger.info("alert message received");
                route = "alertTransformerChannel";
                break;
            case READING:
                logger.info("reading message received");
                route = "readingTransformerChannel";
                break;
        }
        return route;
    }
 }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. Do you want it to ignore the first 10 messages? or to batch up groups of 10 messages at a time?

Comment: Indeed, unclear. Closing the question respectively.

Comment: i need to batch up groups of 10 messages at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need to batch up groups of 10 messages at a time

That is not a `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` responsibility.

We use there `MqttCallback` with this semantic:

```
 * @param topic name of the topic on the message was published to
 * @param message the actual message.
 * @throws Exception if a terminal error has occurred, and the client should be
 * shut down.
 */
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception;
```

So, we can't batch them there on this Channel Adapter by nature of the Paho client.

What we can suggest you from the Spring Integration perspective is an [Aggregator](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Aggregator.html) EIP implementation.

In your case you should add `@ServiceActivator` for the `AggregatorFactoryBean` `@Bean` before that `mqttRouterChannel`, before sending to the router.

That maybe as simple as:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttAggregatorChannel")
AggregatorFactoryBean mqttAggregator() {
    AggregatorFactoryBean aggregator = new AggregatorFactoryBean();
    aggregator.setProcessorBean(new DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor());
    aggregator.setCorrelationStrategy(m -> 1);
    aggregator.setReleaseStrategy(new MessageCountReleaseStrategy(10));
    aggregator.setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(true);
    aggregator.setSendPartialResultOnExpiry(true);
    aggregator.setGroupTimeoutExpression(new ValueExpression<>(1000));
    aggregator.setOutputChannelName("mqttRouterChannel");
    return aggregator;
}
```

See more information in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator).

Comment: thanks  Aggregators sounds like the solution for my case.still learning on how to use Aggregators. thanks again.